# Why I can't hide message after shows once in postback?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have masterpage and its inherit pages. In masterpage I have a literal and i am displaying messages by conditions. In inherit pages I'm creating these messages with stringbuilder.

```
literal.Text = "<div id=\"alertWarning\" style=\"display:none; color:#fff; text-align:center; padding: 8px 10px 9px; width:auto; position:relative; background:#C79810;\"><h3>" + title + "</h3><p>" + error + "</p></div>";

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("$(function() { ");
            sb.Append(" $('#alertWarning').toggle({");
            sb.Append("    width: 400");
            sb.Append(" });");
            sb.Append("});");
            sb.Append("$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop : 0 }, '500');");

            if (HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler is Page)
            {
                Page pa = (Page)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler;

                if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(pa) != null)
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(pa, typeof(Page), "alert", sb.ToString(), true);
                }
                else
                {
                    pa.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "alert", sb.ToString(), true);
                }
            }
```

In masterpage I have this script to autohide display message.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function pageLoad(sender, args) {
            setTimeout(function () { $("#alertError").toggle("close"); }, 5000);
            setTimeout(function () { $("#alertSuccess").toggle("close"); }, 2000);
            setTimeout(function () { $("#alertWarning").toggle("close"); }, 3000);
        };
    </script>
```

But if the page postback that display message displaying again. Is it possible to display it just one time?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would to only add that script if it not a PostBack.

```
    if (HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler is Page)
    {
        Page pa = (Page)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler;
        if(!pa.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(pa) != null)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(pa, typeof(Page), "alert", sb.ToString(), true);
            }
            else
            {
                pa.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "alert", sb.ToString(), true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably, but I also tried and not working. Now I just use very stupid solution to fix that. I just add extra jQuery code in masterpage after existing one. Actually same codes but now toggle replaced by hide function.